# How do I exclude records from an associated model in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating a Q&A application in CakePHP, and I want to exclude my associations in some cases. Imagine the following:

I'm listing all questions on the first page using $this->Question->findAll();. Since I have the following association in my model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Answer' =>
        array('className' => 'Answer',
            'order' => 'Answer.created DESC',
            'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
            'dependent' => true,
            'exclusive' => false,
        )
    );
```

All answers will get selected at the start page, which is not optimal. How could i do to exclude the answers in this particular method?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I quick look at the [CakePHP API](http://api.cakephp.org) reveals that you've got an [unbindModel](http://api.cakephp.org/class_model.html#0b969d5264205cd3a425980dd53e9658) method on the Model.
So in you example you can do this:

```
$this->Question->unBindModel(array('hasMany' => array(’Answer’)))
```

Alternatively, you can use the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable) behaviour to only select the pieces from MySQL that you require for the current page view.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 1.2 you should think about Containable Behaviour. See http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2008/05/18/new-core-behavior-containable/ for details